# how to compare the values from db if the user its in 50m radius

Tags: php, mysql

```
$test_1 = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,l_name,foto_profili FROM users");

while($test = mysql_fetch_array($test_1)){
     $testid = $test['id'];

     $test_2 = mysql_query("SELECT kordinata_x,kordinata_y FROM lokacioni WHERE id_user=$testid");

     while($riinvest = mysql_fetch_array($test_2)){

         $qr_x = $riinvest['kordinata_x'];
         $qr_y = $riinvest['kordinata_y'];

        if($qr_x<=$qr_x+0.001452||$qr_x<=$qr_x-0.001452&&$qr_y<=$qr_y+0.001877||$qr_y<=$qr_y-0.001877){

            echo 'othercode goes here';
        }
    }
}
```

So there is a button where user can send the location of his/her to the database and I am trying to make a check if that user location is inside a circle with a radius of 50m

My problem is that when this code runs all users that have a location saved pop up and the 50m radius code doesnt work

Comment: So what is your specific problem?

Comment: my problem is that when this code runs all users that have a location saved, pop up and the 50m radius code doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the if-condition.

Simplified, you do this comparation:

```
a <= a + x
or 
a <= a - x
and
b <= b + y
or
b <= b - y
```

As some value is always less or equal to the same value plus some other (positive) value, the first and third condition are always true. You must not compare the user coordinates with themselves.

Furthermore, your condition tries to apply a square area instead of a circular area. To calculate the distance, convert the longitude and latitude values to metric positions. Then apply this formula:

```
distance := sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
```

If the result is less or equal to 50, the condition is true.

Based on your code it would look like this in PHP. My PHP isn't very well anymore, so it might contain syntax errors:

```
$test_1 = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,l_name,foto_profili FROM users");

while($test = mysql_fetch_array($test_1)){
    $testid = $test['id'];

    $test_2 = mysql_query("SELECT kordinata_x,kordinata_y FROM lokacioni WHERE id_user=$testid");

    while($riinvest = mysql_fetch_array($test_2)){

        $qr_x = $riinvest['kordinata_x'];
        $qr_y = $riinvest['kordinata_y'];

        <!-- coordToMeters is a fictional function, you have to implement some function that converts coordinates into meters -->
        $qr_x_meters = coordToMeters($qr_x);
        $qr_y_meters = coordToMeters($qr_y);

        <!-- you'll need to provide the coordinates of the center of the circle the users coordinates are checked to be within -->
        $comp_x = ???;
        $comp_y = ???;

        <!-- again, you have to convert them into meters -->
        $comp_x_meters = coordToMeters($comp_x);
        $comp_y_meters = coordToMeters($comp_y);

        <!-- calculate the distance from the circles center to the users position -->
        $distance = sqrt(($comp_x_meters - $qr_x_meters)^2 + ($comp_y_meters - $qr_y_meters)^2);
        if($distance <= 50){
            <!-- do whatever you want to do for those user within the circle -->
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how to fix this
 if($a<=$a+$x||$a<=$a-$x&&$b<=$b+$y||$b<=$b-$y){
     $distance = sqrt(($x2-$x1)^2 + ($y2-$y1)^2
   if($distance <= 50)){

Comment: You don't need to check the four conditions (btw they are still wrong), if you calculate the distance between the users location and the center of the 50m circle. Please notice the distance has to be less or equal 25 meters. I got that wrong first and I will edit my answer to correct it.

Comment: can you write it fully in php please cause its hard for me to understand it like this